# SubSonic Active Record Generate Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, activerecord, subsonic

i wanna use to subsonic 3.0.4 but i dont know, how can i start to generate class and use to new Template of T4.
example: create new solution for generating to table's class and add to my project. ??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You can use it with asp.net, linq and mysql.

You need to follow the procedure shown [**here**](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord).

- Add a Reference to SubSonic
- Add a Connection String - Use MySQL Conn. String
- Set The Connection In The Templates - Update templates and include MySQL.ttinclude instead of SQLServer.ttinclude.
- Add the T4 Templates To Your Project
- Querying - Then you can use your Linq Queries

I think if you follow that link, you will be able to use Subsonic ActiveRecord.

---

First just checkout **[The 5 Minute Demo - ActiveRecord](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo)**.

Then follow: **[Using ActiveRecord Document](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord)**

Demo shows how to use subsonic active record and more configuration is available in docs.

You can find some other docs [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/).

Comment: Thanks, I mean, Im gonna start to asp.net application and i dont wanna work with mvc. Yes, i wanna use to Linq but doesnt depend on Mvc.
In first time, i need to generate my class of db's structure. and also im gonna use to mysql. 
which step i have to start?